# When App in foreground notification contain open automatically

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, foregroundnotification

when my app in foreground then the notification url link open automatically without user's any contribution.

Now,I want to keep notification in notification bar and when user press the notification that will open the url link.
One more thing I have to mention that,when my app in background it works fine.Notification arrive in notification bar.
I want same thing to do for foreground.

please help,
Thanks in advance.

my **FirebaseMessagingServices**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
        String url = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.bellecarib_FCM-MESSAGE");

        intent.putExtra("url",url);

        LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

here is my MainActivity code

```
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mHandler, new IntentFilter("com.bellecarib_FCM-MESSAGE"));


 if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
        for(String key: getIntent().getExtras().keySet()){
            if(key.equals(("url"))){
                mwebView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Opening The Notification Page",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: First, from the code you have pasted can't see you throwing a notification. Rephrase your question. do you want to throw a notification when you receive a message ?

Comment: I received notification while app in foreground and background.

Comment: but when my app in foreground the notification contain open directly without it disposed in notification bar.I want to keep notification in notification bar then when user press the notification it will open as like it open while app in background. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing , is when you send notification payload from FCM. If you want a customised behaviour, then send only a data payload and when you receive the message, throw up a notification manually. This means more work for your app (at the cost of customisation). Also data payloads are delivered with a normal priority which means if your device is in idle mode, then FCM Data payload messages are not delivered immediately and deferred till the next maintenance window (Read upon Android Doze mode and App Standby).

Hope this is clear